# Intersection of SQL statements efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql, intersection, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to solve a SQL problem where I need to select the data in a certain intersection. This is more or less my query:

```sql
SELECT id FROM some_table WHERE
id IN (SELECT id FROM other_table WHERE _id=1 AND some_value >= 1 AND some_value <= 10) AND
id IN (SELECT id FROM another_table WHERE _id=2 AND some_other_value >= -65 AND some_other_value <= -2)
```

The problem with that query is that it does not return the intersection because the `_id` field is different both subqueries. So that query will return an empty result always.

If I use `OR` instead of `AND` to "intersect" the subqueries, then the intersection is also not returned.

I also do not want to use `INTERSECT` because that's kind of slow and this is just a very reduced example of a very large query, so speed is really important.

So, my question is, is there any way to do this intersection as fast as possible? Have in mind that even though in the example only appears two subqueries, in my real use case the number of subqueries can be larger.

Comment: what is `_id` ? Is it different from `id` ?

Comment: Yes, it's different, another kind of id.

Comment: `a very reduced example of a very large query` post *that* query then. A query's execution plan isn't composed from the execution plans of subqueries. The query is parsed as a whole, simplified and then the query optimizer decides what techniques to use based on the available indexes and data statistics.

Comment: I cannot share the whole query because it's really complex with a ton of different use cases that do not apply to my current problem.

Comment: Besides, your query doesn't perform any intersections. Effectively it joins one table with two others. It's unclear what results you want to retrieve- `some_table` rows with matching rows in either of the other tables? Or only those found in both of the other tables?

Comment: Sample data and expected results from your example would be a +  also, "I also do not want to use INTERSECT because that's kind of slow and this is just a very reduced example of a very large query, so speed is really important."  INTERSECT operates on  a "SET" basis these are by far and away the most efficient of queries.  So if you're trying to get the intersection of two datasets, and intersect isn't working.... something else is wrong; or it's not being used correctly, or the problem isn't defined correctly.  Also an INNER Join on ID instead of where in. means the ID exists in both...

Comment: I think it's indeed trying to make an intersection (emphasis on the trying part). I want the ids from some_table that satisfies the conditions of the first subquery AND the second subquery.

Comment: Simplify your query, maybe you should prefer `EXISTS(...)` ?

Comment: @xQbert are you saying then that intersect is not slow? I had read on the internet that it was quite slow.

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado ` that do not apply to my current problem.` actually it does. I already explained that the parts of the query aren't executed in isolation. The execution plan is generated for the entire query. While the server may use one index if a subquery was executed independently, it will use a different one, or none at all, if that query is part of a larger one. If T1  and T2 have only eg 10 rows each, any indexes on them will be useless when joining with a 100K row table T3. The server may decide to *not* use any indexes on T1 and T2, caching them instead

Comment: Please provide information for your performance question as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info. Postgres version, table definitions, cardinalities, indexes: all of those are essential for the best solution.

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado yes I'm saying set based operations such as EXCEPT, INTERSECT, UNION, UNION ALL are not inherently slow.  And if you're really only after records (IDs) which exist in two distinct sets, then intersect seems like a good choice here... Of course there may be a bug or something in your RDBMS version/patch that is causing issues; but that isn't an intended feature by the vendor.  how a set operator is used maybe sub optimal; but the feature itself is not.

Comment: If the original query is large and complex, why do you think that this rather small fragment is causing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still unclear on what you're after w/o sample data or expected results, but would either of the following options work?

##### using INNER JOIN

```sql
SELECT id 
  FROM some_table A
 INNER JOIN (
       SELECT id
         FROM other_table
        WHERE _id = 1
          AND some_value >= 1
          AND some_value <= 10
 ) B on A.ID = B.ID
 INNER JOIN (
       SELECT id
         FROM another_table
        WHERE _id = 2
          AND some_other_value >= -65
          AND some_other_value <= -2
 ) C ON C.ID = A.ID
```

##### using INTERSECT

```sql
SELECT id
  FROM some_table
INTERSECT
SELECT id
  FROM other_table
 WHERE _id = 1
   AND some_value >= 1
   AND some_value <= 10
INTERSECT 
SELECT id
  FROM another_table
 WHERE _id = 2
   AND some_other_value >= -65
   AND some_other_value <= -2


Then, I suppose we could use `EXISTS` and correlated subquery—instead of `IN`. This can be faster, as `EXISTS` can escape early whereas `IN` cannot.
```